# Angular 2 calling Web Api with json results not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular

My call with Angular 1.5.x  needed to have  `Devices` added to `result.data`

`result.data.Devices`

Thus my Angular 1.x  $http call was like this:

```
var vm = this;
var dataService = $http;

dataService.get("http://localhost:42822/api/device")
        .then(function (result) {

vm.devices = result.data.Devices;
```

**My Angular 2 code is a bit different,  I'm calling same web api**

If I call up a .json file then it works to display

```
private _productUrl = 'api/devices/devices.json';
```

But I'm not understanding some of this code of which I do not see where to really ADD the "Devices"

```
private _productUrl = 'http://localhost:42822/api/device';

constructor(private _http: Http) { }

getProducts(): Observable<IDevice[]> {//Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IDevice[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Wouldn't this be where I would add in "Device"  or in html template?

Comment: That could be because of `IDevice` definition. try to use `any` instead of `IDevice`.

Comment: It doesn't sound like that would be his problem since he is saying that his .json file is working  `If I call up a .json file then it works to display`   So I'm guessing his interface is OK.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED

`getProducts` returns Observable collection that could be subscribe on changed

`.map((response: Response) => <IDevice[]>response.json())`

this returns list of your devices after http request done.

says `getProducts` is defined as controller method you can subscribe to observable collection like this.

`getProducts().subscribe(data => this.vm.devices = data)`

or better separate the it into services (eg. DataService)

```
// constructor
constructor (private dataService: DataService) {}

displayData(): {
    this.dataService.getProducts()
        .subscribe(data => this.vm.devices = data);
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP even has a "vm" because in their code they were talking about "vm.devices"  with Angular 1 , but they never showed any such object in the Angular 2 section code ... I assume it is not there...

Comment: I do not have a `vm`      not sure how to do this     .subscribe(data => this.vm.devices = data); .....