# Web Api Data in JSON is wrapped in an object , why is this and how can I tell the Web Api owner what to do to fix this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to consume some Web Api data in which it is handled by a different team and they do not seem to think there is anything wrong with the data.

While I realize that it is valide JSON,  I would like to tell them what I prefer them send in order to not have more work to do on my client end.

Postman and Angular ( anything )   ends up getting the data wrapped in this "Devices"

```
{
  "Devices": [
    {
      "DeviceId": "00022B9A000000010001",
      "StagedManifestIdList": [],
      "PendingManifestId": null,
      "PendingTimeStamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "ManifestIdList": [
        "00000002",
        "00000001",
        "00000003"
      ],
      "DeviceStatus": 3,
      "Aid": "oAAABTUAAg==",
      "DKiIndex": "DKi00000002",
      "Sha": "R2tiZRQgY/iohXZt5O4HaQwtVe/adWU2VOcKaelJ3Us=",
      "DefaultPayload": "C:\\ProgramData\\ABC\\124\\Payloads\\M4PayloadAuto.xml"
    }
  ]
}
```

So above the **Devices** is just painful for me to work with.

They DID send me the code of their Web Api Method,  what can they change so I do not get this "Device" wrapper name?

```
public class DeviceController : ApiController
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (DeviceController).Name);

        [ResponseType(typeof (RetrieveDeviceResponse))]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string id = null)
        {
            IHttpActionResult httpActionResult;
            var returnVal = new RetrieveDeviceResponse();

            try
            {
                byte[] deviceIdBytes = null;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
                {
                    deviceIdBytes = ByteArray.ConvertHexStringToByteArray(id);
                }

                var deviceInfoArray = DeviceManager.RetrieveDevice(deviceIdBytes);

                if (deviceInfoArray == null)
                {
                    returnVal.Success = false;
                    returnVal.ErrorMessage = "Get: RetrieveDevice returned null";
                }
                else
                {
                    returnVal.Devices = new List<DeviceInfo>();

                    foreach (var deviceInfoObj in deviceInfoArray)
                    {
                        DeviceInfo deviceInfo = new DeviceInfo
                        {
                            Aid = deviceInfoObj.AID,
                            DKiIndex = deviceInfoObj.DKiIndex,
                            DefaultPayload = deviceInfoObj.DefaultPayload,
                            DeviceId = ByteArray.ConvertToHexString(deviceInfoObj.DevID),
                            StagedManifestIdList = deviceInfoObj.StagedManifestIDList,
                            PendingManifestId = deviceInfoObj.PendingManifestID,
                            PendingTimeStamp = deviceInfoObj.PendingTimeStamp,
                            ManifestIdList = deviceInfoObj.ManifestIDList,
                            DeviceStatus = (DeviceStatus) deviceInfoObj.DeviceStatus,
                            Sha = deviceInfoObj.SHA
                        };

                        returnVal.Devices.Add(deviceInfo);
                    }

                    returnVal.Success = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                returnVal.ErrorMessage = "Get: Exception. " + DebugMode.ShowMessage(ex.Message);
                returnVal.Success = false;
                Log.Error(returnVal.LastErrorMessage);
            }


            if (returnVal.Success)
            {
                httpActionResult = Ok(returnVal);
                Log.Debug("Get: Success");
            }
            else
            {
                httpActionResult = Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, returnVal);
                Log.Error("Get Failed: " + returnVal.ErrorMessage);
            }

            return httpActionResult;
        }

    }
```

Comment: "Painful"?? Why is that painful? Why do you even care?

Comment: $http of Angular is just slightly a bit more syntax   `result.data.Devices;`   but $resource I end up getting mixed results with it and $httpBackend

Comment: Just filter out the data in your service layer. You're not going to get a team to change how they send you data because it's not formatted how *you* want it.

Comment: For Example - Here is when I was trying to do it in Angular 2 , and I never moved forward with figuring it out within this code    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112342/angular-2-calling-web-api-with-json-results-not-displaying

Comment: @tymeJV    -  How can I consistently filter it out?   Can you post an answer with an example of how of maybe a method or something that you would suggest to filter this out ?

Comment: @Amit   --  how would you filter it out ?

Comment: Only return the data you want - you can use `Array.map` to iterate the devices array and just return the fields you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please say exactly why is it painful? As I can see, they are returning not only info about devices, but also exceptions and success statuses. For example, if there will be an error, you will receive something like that:

```
{
  "Devices": [], 
  "ErrorMessage" : "Some Error Message",
  "Success" : false
}
```

It is possible that ignoring this will lead to some problems.

However, if you insist that you need only a list of `Devices` and nothing else, tell them to return not `returnVal` wrapped in `HttpActionResult`, but `returnVal.Devices`. For example, change this

```
  if (returnVal.Success)
  {
       httpActionResult = Ok(returnVal);
       Log.Debug("Get: Success");
  }
```

To this:

```
  if (returnVal.Success)
  {
       httpActionResult = Ok(returnVal.Devices);
       Log.Debug("Get: Success");
  }
```

However, I insist you to use what they provide. It is very simple and not painful to get `Devices` on client-side from their provided object.

Comment: I agree with not having them change their web api code,  but it is just dificult depending on the page that I am using.   I suppose that I should do a Plunker to show.   Here was my challenge with that data with Angular 2 with using an observable  - the answers did not help    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112342/angular-2-calling-web-api-with-json-results-not-displaying